# Ordenação acentuada com javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho a seguinte função para ordenar, mas, não ordena corretamente as palavras acentuadas

```
ordenaNomeCompleto: function(a,b){
    var ans = 0;
    if(a.nome_completo < b.nome_completo) ans = -1
    if(a.nome_completo > b.nome_completo) ans = 1
   return ans;
    },
```

Procurando na Internet eu encontrei este método:

```
ans  = a.localeCompare(b)
```

mas, tem a seguinte mensagem no console

```
a.localeCompare is not a function
```

Alugém tem uma dica para resolver este problema com javascript puro?

Comment: `a` é uma string?

Comment: Não deveria usar `a.nome_completo.localComparte(b.nome_completo)`? Pois elas são as strings que deveriam ser comparadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que `a`, no seu código, é um objeto, e o `localeCompare` é um método da classe `string`. Na verdade, você deveria comparar o atributo `nome_completo` dos objetos `a` e `b`. Portanto, seu código ficaria assim:

```
ordenaNomeCompleto: function(a,b){
    var ans = a.nome_completo.localeCompare(b.nome_completo);
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: @MathuesReis Continua dando a resposta no console:
`TypeError: a.nome_completo.localCompare is not a function`

Comment: Eu escrevi `local` ao invés de `locale`. Modifique e tente novamente, por favor, @LuisSouza

Comment: Funcionou que é uma beleza! Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Eu vou fazer outra pergunta, mas, ordenação descrecente